# PHP array not pushing elements

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have the following code:

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$requests = array();

addSentimentHandle ( 'Hello', $requests );
addSentimentHandle ( 'Hello :)', $requests );

function addSentimentHandle($tweet, $requests) {
    $url = makeURLForAPICall($tweet);
    array_push($requests, curl_init ($url));
    print_r($requests);
}
```

I would expect the `$requests` array to contain two elements, however this is the output:

`Array ( [0] => Resource id #8 ) Array ( [0] => Resource id #9 )`

**Why are 2 arrays are being created instead of the second item being pushed into the same array?**

Comment: I believe you're pushing to a local instance inside `addSentimentHandle()`, have you tried passing the array by reference? `function addSentimentHandle($tweet, &$requests) {}`

Comment: Silly, silly me. Thank you, it works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you want to use $requests as a global variable.
In your code it's not.
You should pass it as a reference:

```php
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$requests = array();

addSentimentHandle ( 'Hello', $requests );
addSentimentHandle ( 'Hello :)', $requests );

function addSentimentHandle($tweet, &$requests) {
    $url = makeURLForAPICall($tweet);
    array_push($requests, curl_init ($url));
    print_r($requests);
}
```

note the '&' as a prefix for $requests in function declaration. Then php wont used it as a local variable in this function.

I recommend to you to use php as an object oriented language.

```php
class myAwesomeTweeterClass{
 protected $_requests;

 public function __construct(){
  $this->_requests = array();
 }

 public function addSentimentHandle($tweet) {
    $url = makeURLForAPICall($tweet);
    array_push($this->_requests, curl_init ($url));
 }
 public function getRequests(){
    return $this->_requests;
 }
}
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$obj = new myAwesomeTweeterClass();
$obj->addSentimentHandle ( 'Hello');
$obj->addSentimentHandle ( 'Hello :)');
print_r($obj->getRequests());
```